# how to maintain state of uibutton in table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I have a table view in that I am using a `custom cell`. I have two buttons on each table view cell named "edit" and "cancel" both have images in `cellForRow`. What I want that when user clicks on edit button at same time same rows cancel button should change its image. Code is Working but it not changing same rows cancel button image. Its changing another rows cancel button image. How to maintain state of each button.

Here Is Code

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuNameCell";
  MenuNameCell *cell = (MenuNameCell *)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

     if (cell== nil) {
     NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuNameCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"---------new cell agin");   
}
   else
       [cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];


// Creating Label Menu Name
_nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 11, 82, 21)];
_nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_nameLabel.text =  [_hotel._orderedMenus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Creating Label Menu Cost
_amountMenu   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(167, 13, 44, 21)];
_amountMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_amountMenu.text  = [[_hotel._menuPrices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

// Creating Text Field For Order Quantity
_textFieldQuantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,14,42,21)];
_textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
_textFieldQuantity.text = [[_hotel._selectedQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

//Creating Button For CANCEL Order
_cancelButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(265, 13, 25, 28)];
[_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_cancelButton setTag:indexPath.row];
[_cancelButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(cancelOreder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Creating Button For Check Order
_checkButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 13, 25, 28)];
[_checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];
[_checkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Adding All To Content View
[cell.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_amountMenu];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldQuantity];

[cell.contentView addSubview:_checkButton];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_cancelButton];

//objc_setAssociatedObject(_checkButton, iindex, indexPath,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN );

return cell;
 }

-(void)editQuantity:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"count of the array is----%d",[imageViewArray count]);
button = (UIButton *)sender;
row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"---rowww%d",row);
_textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_over.png"];

[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
[_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _cancelButton.tag =  0;
}

-(void)cancelOreder:(id)sender{
button = (UIButton *)sender;
row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"The Row Selected iS At Cancel Order ISSSS----%d", row);
if (_cancelButton.tag ==  0){
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_over.png"];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImageCancel1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _cancelButton.tag = 1;
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iHomeDelivery" message:@"Do You Want To Cancel the Order" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not placing the buttons in the custom cell an let the cell managing the states. So just delegating a button pressed to your view controller?

Comment: your solution is good. but when i am trying to do this application crashed at time of scrolling

Comment: Where is the point of failure? What error do you get? Could you post the code you have when using the cell with buttons?

Comment: i got solution by anushs approach

Comment: if @anusha's answer help you then accept her answer so in future other can see the true answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to make _cancelButton and _checkButton with different tag in the same cell, I think it is puzzle to make both of them with same tag in the same row.

Comment: @JigneshKalantri right, but "+100" may cause another problem, it would be puzzle again when there are more than 100 cells.

Comment: ya i understanstand i have given 1000. i know its not good. will try another approach

Comment: if you have any other optin pls let mekno

Answer (score 0):

Give different tag for each buttons first like :

```
[_checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];

[_cancelButton setTag:indexPath.row+100];
```

and in your `editQuantity:` method

```
button = (UIButton *)sender;
row = button.tag;

NSIndexPath *currentIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *newCell = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath];

newCancelButton = (UIButton *)[newCell.contentView viewWithTag:row+100];

[newCancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Do same in your `cancelOreder:` method to change image of _checkButton.

Also, use this for remove all subViews,

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: when i scroll down table view again default image are applied for button give me solution on this also

Comment: @JigneshKalantri Did you change the code for removing cell subviews as given in my answer??

Comment: @JigneshKalantri While scrolling each cell will reload and image will change as in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. To fix that you have to check that inside the method..

Comment: @JigneshKalantri ...for that store the edited cell indexPath.row in an array and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: check current row in that array or not for set the image

Comment: one more thing anusha i have placed textField in each row cell i want that if user selct third cell edit button same time third cell textfeild userinterction is enabled how we can do this?

Comment: @JigneshKalantri same as retrieving cancel button reference in your edit method retrieve the textField reference also using tag... Then you can set userInteraction..

Answer (score 0):

please try this solution

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL_ID"];
  if(cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL_ID"];

    UIButton *_cancelButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(65, 13, 100, 28)];
    [_cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_cancelButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(cancelOreder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_cancelButton setTag:1];

    UIButton *_checkButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [_checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 13, 100, 28)];
    [_checkButton setTitle:@"Check" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkButton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_checkButton setTag:2];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:_checkButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_cancelButton];
  }
  return cell;
}

-(void) cancelOreder:(id)sender
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[(UIButton *)sender superview];
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
  if(btn != nil)
  {
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
}

-(void) editQuantity:(id)sender
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[(UIButton *)sender superview];
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
  if(btn != nil)
  {
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
}
```

in this example i cheange text color of label you can change image,hope this will help you